# cmd format user input and use for next commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to translate input formatted like this: abcd12-34defg and translate it to this: ab-cd-12-34-de-fg
and use fixed/translated output in the same batch for next commands as variable

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p macID="please enter mac id:" 

call :print_token 0 2 -
call :print_token 2 2 -
call :print_token 4 2 -
call :print_token 7 2 -
call :print_token 9 2 -
call :print_token 11 2 

goto :eof

:print_token
echo | set /p dummyVar=!macID:~%1,%2!%3
exit /b 0
```

Current output:

```
please enter mac id: abcd12-34defg    
abcd12-34defg
```

Goal:

```
please enter mac id: abcd12-34defg    
ab-cd-12-34-de-fg
....any_future_cmd_command "%my_new_mac_id_from_2nd_line%"
```

(this should be kept "cache" in the batch for next following commands like for example: )

netsh dhcp server \myserver scope myscope | find /i"%my_new_mac_id_from_2nd_line%"

thx for your patience

Comment: Your description is wrong, your code currently outputs `ab-cd-12-34-de-fg` already. Why you output the parts of the MAC instead of collecting them in a variable?

Comment: sorry you are right, so how to collect them in a variable ?)

Comment: This works _as requested_: `set /P "ID=Enter mac id:"` followed by  `set "newMac=%ID:~0,2%-%ID:~2,2%-%ID:~4,2%-%ID:~7,2%-%ID:~9,2%-%ID:~11,2%"`. Is there any _additional_ requirement?

Comment: @Aacini short and easy thx that s great !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p macID="please enter mac id:" 
set finalMacID=

call :get_token token %macID% 0 2 -
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%
call :get_token token %macID% 2 2 -
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%
call :get_token token %macID% 4 2 -
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%
call :get_token token %macID% 7 2 -
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%
call :get_token token %macID% 9 2 -
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%
call :get_token token %macID% 11 2 
set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%

echo %finalMacID% 
goto :eof

:get_token
set fullString=%2
set %1=!fullString:~%3,%4!%5
exit /b 0
```

As I told you in your previous post, if you decide to clean the `macID` provided by the user, you can accomplish a cleaner solution, as you can put all the `call :add_token_to_variable.... set finalMacID=%finalMacID%%token%` statements in one single for loop, making it more compact and less error prone.

Hope it helps.

Comment: great ! now i get it ^^

Comment: @deschus great. anyway, keep in mind my suggestion to clean the input before processing it, as it is less error prone and easier for you to further develop your batch file...

Comment: With `!1!` in the `:get_token` function you mean `%1`, right?

Comment: @aschipfl if I don't use !1!, the token variable won't get the proper value. This would be the resulting value stored in the `finalMacID` variable in that case: `tokenab-tokencd-token12-token34-tokende-tokenfg`

Comment: But there is no variable called `1` (and such variable name was a bad idea anyway)! It should read `!%1!` as `%1` expands to `token`, which is in turn expanded by the surrounding `!!`.

Comment: @aschipfl I'm not sure I follow. `%1` is a parameter (hence the non-descriptive name), that I want to reference using delayed expansion, hence the `!1!`. I am open to suggestions to improve the code, but the one you suggest will generate this output: `ab-ab-cd-ab-cd-12-ab-cd-12-34-ab-cd-12-34-de-ab-cd-12-34-de-fg` which isn't what's expected.

Comment: You cannot reference to a command line argument reference `%1` using delayed expansion, the `!!` syntax works *only* for true environment variables; I just realised that you do the assembly of the final string outside of `:get_token`, so there is no need for `!1!` after all, so you should simply remove it, because it is expanded to an empty string anyway (as there is no environment variable called `1`)...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for your patience. You are right. I just updated my answer... thanks for helping me understand!

Answer (score 1):

To collect all parts in a variable you could change your `:print_token` function slightly to.

```
:print_token
set "MAC=!MAC!!macID:~%1,%2!%3"
exit /b
```

And use `set "MAC="` to clear it, before the first call of your function.